# VS4M install failing with 404 error

Tags: c#, xamarin, http-status-code-404, visual-studio-mac

```
Error downloading from Xamarin server. Visual Studio for Mac Preview.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1025
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1037
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse (System.Func`1[TResult] createRequest, System.Action`1[T] prepareRequest) [0x0023e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/MonoDevelop.Core.Web/RequestHelper.cs:83

Error downloading from Xamarin server. Visual Studio for Mac Preview.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1025
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1037
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse (System.Func`1[TResult] createRequest, System.Action`1[T] prepareRequest) [0x0023e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/MonoDevelop.Core.Web/RequestHelper.cs:83

Visual Studio for Mac Preview installation failed with more than one exception (Attempt #3)
Some installation errors are present.
Exception type: System.AggregateException
Message: Some installation errors are present.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Message: Download failed.
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem () [0x0008f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:543
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:301
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinIDEBase.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/XamarinIDEBase.Mac.cs:74
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.VisualStudioMacSoftwareItem.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/VisualStudioMacSoftwareItem.Mac.cs:12
at MacInstaller.WizardPageInstallationController.InstallationWorker () [0x00145] in <bec2fcecac0e4432887144872f1d5045>:0
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1025
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1037
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse (System.Func`1[TResult] createRequest, System.Action`1[T] prepareRequest) [0x0023e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/MonoDevelop.Core.Web/RequestHelper.cs:83
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Message: Download failed.
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem () [0x0008f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:543
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:301
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinIDEBase.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/XamarinIDEBase.Mac.cs:74
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.VisualStudioMacSoftwareItem.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/VisualStudioMacSoftwareItem.Mac.cs:12
at MacInstaller.WizardPageInstallationController.InstallationWorker () [0x00145] in <bec2fcecac0e4432887144872f1d5045>:0
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1025
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1037
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse (System.Func`1[TResult] createRequest, System.Action`1[T] prepareRequest) [0x0023e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/MonoDevelop.Core.Web/RequestHelper.cs:83
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Message: Download failed.
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem () [0x0008f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:543
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:301
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.XamarinIDEBase.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/XamarinIDEBase.Mac.cs:74
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.VisualStudioMacSoftwareItem.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/VisualStudioMacSoftwareItem.Mac.cs:12
at MacInstaller.WizardPageInstallationController.InstallationWorker () [0x00145] in <bec2fcecac0e4432887144872f1d5045>:0
Exception type: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1025
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1037
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse (System.Func`1[TResult] createRequest, System.Action`1[T] prepareRequest) [0x0023e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/MonoDevelop.Core.Web/RequestHelper.cs:83
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: The official RTM build of Visual Studio for Mac has shipped, so any Preview build should go away.

Comment: @CSharpRocks - What exactly would you like me to have asked? Since Microsoft bought Xamarin, I can't go to their support any longer, and am forced to post issues on SO, per their own instructions. Issues with Xamarin are to be posted to the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

Redownloaded the installer and all seems to be well. Might have caught them in the midst of a migration?